# Logic - Existential quantification and axiom of choice

Tags: first-order-logic

I am new to logic and struggling to understand the very basics of first-order logic.

Suppose $ \forall x \exists y: P(x,y) $. Since the existence does not imply uniqueness, for all $x$, I can choose a single value from possibly multiple values of $y$. Now I should invoke the axiom of choice to say that there is a (choice) function $c$ such that $\forall x : P(x, c(x))$. It seems the underlying logic of existential instantiation [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Existential_instantiation). Is this correct?